# How set another view(text view or imageview ) inside VrPanoramaView?

Tags: android, virtual-reality, android-viewholder

I have a VrPanoramaView which I am loading with an image. I want to add a subview inside the VrPanoramaView. I am adding it by using the following code snippet.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Sample Text");
tv.setTextSize(12);
panoWidgetView.addView(tv);
```

But I am not able to see that newly added text view inside the VrPanoramaView.

Help me with the useful tips.